# Error: Syntax error in input(3). When using typedef'd type

Tags: c++, swig

I get this error when using swig with go:

```
root@linux:~/go/src/kytea# go build
# kytea
/root/go/kyteagit/src/include/kytea/string-util.h:36: Error: Syntax error in input(3).
```

The project is [this one](https://github.com/neubig/kytea). And the line in question is:

```
[...]
27    namespace kytea {
28    
29    // a class for turning std::strings into internal representation
30    class StringUtil {
31    
32    public:
33    
34        // types of characters (set in the constructor)
35        typedef char CharType;
36        const static CharType KANJI    = 'K';
37        const static CharType KATAKANA = 'T';
38        const static CharType HIRAGANA = 'H';
39        const static CharType ROMAJI   = 'R';
40        const static CharType DIGIT    = 'D';
41        const static CharType OTHER    = 'O';
[...]
```

Based on other similar issues with swig I am guessing it has something to do with swig not being able to parse the line, how can I correct this without having to change the source code?

Comment: The code snippet above has not problem by itself.  I suspect another include to cause havoc (for example a missing `}` or a macro) or problems in the cpp that include this file.

Comment: @Christophe - thanks for your comment - I came across this trying to solve the same problem in a commit I had just made to a different project, and it was indeed caused by a missing `}` in my case